# Is [kotlin-symbol-processing] the successor of [ksp]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

When looking at newly created tags, I found [kotlin-symbol-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-symbol-processing).

[Kotlin symbol processing (KSP) is an API that allows to generate [tag:kotlin] code at compile-time](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-overview.html).

Previously, people used the [ksp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ksp) tag for tagging questions about the Kotlin Symbol Processing API.

On StackOverflow, there currently are

- [13 questions with both [ksp] and [kotlin]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ksp+kotlin) + [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70898387/how-to-configure-ksp-in-my-android-gradle-groovy-dsl-build-files) that is about Kotlin Symbol processing as well
- [6 other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ksp+-kotlin+-android) that mostly seem to be about Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider (which I don't know much about).
- [20 [ksp] questions in total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ksp)

Should we remove [ksp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ksp) and split it up into (the new) [kotlin-symbol-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-symbol-processing) and something like [microsoft-key-storage-provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-key-storage-provider)?

If so, should we somehow make sure that people looking for KSP find those new tags?

Comment: I think `microsoft-ksp` would work for Microsoft key storage provider questions, since the KSP abbreviation is well known and documented.

Comment: I guess the same applies to `kotlin-ksp` as well (e.g. [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-overview.html) also refer to Kotlin Symbol Processing as KSP).

Comment: Synonyms are easier that way too _e.g._ [kotlin-ksp] -> [kotlin-symbol-processing] or vice versa (if needed)

Comment: Good 'ol Kotlin Kotlin Symbol Processing.  The Department of Redundancy Department would approve.

Comment: Was I the only one wondering what the Kerbal Space Program has to do with anythin?

Comment: BTW, each MS framework seems to have their own flavor of storage provider with their own api. This thing is too generic. Better to go up a level: microsoft-cng for the next generation crypto api; asp.net-core for the crypto api that it provides (which supports more than the CNG one, including Redis, windows registry, etc.). is other missing.

Comment: I suspect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69156686/ksp-principia-how-do-i-extend-the-future-track is in fact about kerbal space program, purely on account of "ksp principia" being a mod, explicitly defining microsoft in searches doesn't yield any non-space program hits, and "Max History Length" is indeed a setting in the principia mod. There's also the mention of "ship" and future prediction, and I fail to see how either of those two are relevant to MS KSP. Clearing out the rest now, but leaving this particular one here for auditing purposes.